# im trying to get total count from a column containing 'New' and 'Used' from a csv file using php

Tags: php, arrays, csv, foreach, count

I am trying to get the total count for new and used cars from the column "type" in a csv file. I output the data fine but cant seem to figure out out to split up the new and used count..

Here is what im using -

```
// Set path to CSV file
$csvFile = 'csv/File.csv';
$csv = readCSV($csvFile);
array_shift($csv); 

$count = count($csv); // Gives Total New and Used (400)

foreach($csv as $car){
$type = $car[0]; // defines New or Used Car
$used = ($type == "Used"); //(Should be 108)
$new = ($type == "New");   //(Should be 292)
}
```

Now how would I get the total count for each new and used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very simple logic.

```
    $used = 0;  $new = 0;
    foreach($csv as $car){
        $type = $car[0]; // defines New or Used Car
        if($type == "Used"){
            $used++; //(Should be 108)
        } 
        if($type == "New"){
            $new++; //(Should be 292)
        }   
    }
echo "Used Cars : ". $used ."<br>";
echo "New Cars : ". $new ."<br>";
```

Comment: ya I was way over thinking it, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this one :

```
foreach($csv as $car){
$type = $car[0];
$used += ($type == "Used")?1:0;
$new += ($type == "New")?1:0;
}
```